# Compatibility issues with IE11 and Office web add-in using Typescript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Office web add-in using Typescript + React following the MS document here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

I have used Typescript + ES6 code. The Office add-in already has references to Babel and Core-JS (I have not done any additional config)

The add-in works fine on modern browser like Chrome and Edge. However, with IE11 (and Safari on Mac OSX) the add-in does not load (displays a blank page/taskpane). Looking at the console logs I see these errors:

- Syntax error -> pointing to an arrow function within vendor.js and taskpane.js files
- Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page

I have reference to babel in my webpack.config.js file like so:

`{ test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: { loader: "babel-loader", options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"], }, }, }`

my babel.config.json file has the following:

`{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"] }`

Comment: Wait, I thought IE11 was dead and buried.

Comment: Unfortunately we need to cater for IE11 still + the desktop Outlook app uses IE11 as its backend

Comment: Can you try to add either Office.onReady() or Office.initialize in your addin? It is possible that Office context is not fully loaded and causing error in your addin. For more details on how to intialize please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in